# Can I assign and return without a utility routine?

Tags: c++, reference, return, conditional-operator, assignment-operator

Is there a way to "assign and return" without creating a utility routine?  Here's my code:

```
static int& do_work_(const int* p, int& result)
{
   result = (*p) * 10;
   return result;
}

template<typename T>
T& assign(const T* p, T& result)
{
   result = *p;
   return result;
}

int& do_work(const int* p, bool cond, int& result)
{
   return cond ? do_work_(p, result) : assign(p, result);
}
```

Can I implement `do_work()` without the `assign()` utility?

---

The reason for the `do_work()` signature is that it's a nice convenience:

```
const int value=1;
int i, j;
if (do_work(&value, true, i) == do_work(&value, false, j)) {}
```

Comment: Do you really want to _both_ 1) return the result and also 2) use one of the parameters as output (return) parameter?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but isn't `return result = *p;` exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: `return cond ? (result = *p) : (result = *p * 10);`? `return result = *p * (cond ? 1 : 10);`

Comment: Then you want `return cond ? do_work_(p, result) : (result = *p);`? I think you should be able to figure it out by now.

Comment: Note that the evaluation order of the `==` operands in your "convenient" use case is unspecified. If you pass the same object by reference in both, you might find yourself with a bug that's very nasty to locate.

Comment: @JackBrown that wasn't meant to be mean in any way, I just didn't know what you're actually asking for - here's some sample code btw https://godbolt.org/z/d5r56hbPG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return the result of an assignment operation you can (in most cases) do so without a 'utility' function like your `assign`, because the assignment expression *itself* has a value; [from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment) (bolding mine):

> The direct assignment operator expects a modifiable lvalue as its left
> operand and an rvalue expression or a braced-init-list (since C++11)
> as its right operand, **and returns an lvalue identifying the left
> operand after modification**.

Or, from [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 8.5.18 Assignment and compound assignment operators       [expr.ass]
>
> <sup>1</sup>   The
> assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all
> group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
> operand; **their result is an lvalue referring to the left operand**.
> …

Thus, as suggested in the comments, you can simply have the following:

```cpp
int& do_work(const int* p, bool cond, int& result)
{
   return cond ? do_work_(p, result) : (result = *p);
}
```